# Calling Item_command Event from page_load function

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Scenario:I** have two divs on a page div1 contains datalist (datalist1) and div2 contains controls that are populated on item-command event of data-list.

**Problem**: I want to call item_command event for 1st element of datalist1 on page_Load.
how can I do that and what parameters shall i pass to item_command event?

item_command event:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{

      DataList1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;

                if (e.CommandName.Equals("MID"))
                {
         AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());// a global variable

                    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                    var memos = (from m in db.Memos
                                 where m.memoId == AnswerId
                                 select m).First();


                       legendtitle.InnerText = memos.title.ToString();


                    TextBox2.Text = memos.description.ToString();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your event handler contains code that you want to run independently of the event firing, refactor the method to remove that code to a separate method. (Probably everything after setting AnswerId.) Then you can call that separate method without faking event args.

Comment: What I gather from your reply is I should remove code from item_command event and place it in some other method.
Actually, I am using item_command event later. When an item is selected from datalist.
I just want to get first item selected by default when page first loads.

Comment: I realize that. Let's say you remove the code that follows setting AnswerId, and place it in a method `private void displayItem()`. Then, in `DataList1_ItemCommand` where that code used to be, add the line `displayItem();`. Finally, in your page load, set AnswerId as you wish, and add the line `displayItem();`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

call this method on page_load as

```
BindingMethod(0);            //for 1st selection
```

and in DataList1_ItemCommand as

```
BindingMethod(e.Item.ItemIndex);
```

and declare method as below

```
public void BindingMethod(int index)

{
 DataList1.SelectedIndex = index;

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("MID"))
            {
     AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[index].ToString());// a global variable

                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                var memos = (from m in db.Memos
                             where m.memoId == AnswerId
                             select m).First();


                   legendtitle.InnerText = memos.title.ToString();


                TextBox2.Text = memos.description.ToString(); 


}
```